# Is there something wrong with my code in Python

Tags: python

This is what I did during my free time, but for some reason whenever I try this code, I get everything. The goal for it is to pick a random number from 1 to 6. 
Instead, this is what I get

```
number = 1,2,3,4,5,6

import random

for i in range(20):
    question= raw_input("Do you want a number from 1 to 6")
    if question == "yes":
        print number
    elif question == "no":
        print "Ok"
```

[image]

Comment: what is the problem you're trying to solve? what is the question you're trying to answer?

Comment: try to be more specific with your question title

Comment: What did you expect `print number` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `number` is the tuple `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`, so this is working as expected. 
If you want to select a random number from that set, you might try using the `random.sample` function

Example:

```
import random
result = random.sample(numbers, 1)    
print result  # will produce one number from the set
```

or, if you know that you're always going to be using a selection from a contiguous range, you can use `randint`

Comment: You think they want the number in a list?

Comment: only because that's how the OP specified the problem originally :)

Comment: I checked the revision history and can't find anything that says so...

Comment: `number = 1,2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: First of all, that's not a list but a tuple, and secondly, I'm talking about "the number" they "want". As in, the *output*. Your output is one number in a list.

Comment: Ah, I get you. Sure, they can use that example to produce whatever they need.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

Sample code :

```
>>> import random
>>> number = [1,2,3,4,5]

>>> for i in range(3): 
        print(random.choice(number)) 
=>  5
    4
    2
```

---

From python docs :

> **random.choice(seq)**
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence
>   seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.

---

As for the problem in your code, you are not getting any randomly generated numbers or selecting from the `tuple`, but are rather just printing the whole `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's wrong in your code you just printing list of ints. To get a random number you need to use `random.randint` function like:

```
import random
for i in range(20):
    question= raw_input("Do you want a number from 1 to 6")
    if question == "yes":
        print random.randint(1, 6)
    elif question == "no":
        print "Ok"`
```